# Is there any C++ API for Decision Tree in TensorFlow to solve Decision Tree based problems

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I would like to use TensorFlow C++ API instead of TensorFlow Python for below problem to forecast whether one will be able to play the game in the given weather conditions using ML Decision tree.

I have seen Tensorflow Python code for decision tree based problems but couldn't find any C++ API in Tensorflow. mlpack supports C++ class for decision tree based problems, so wanted to know, are we have any C++ API's in Tensorflow to solve decision tree based problems?

I am trying to solve below problem using Tensorflow C++.

Here are the train and test data sets. Based on this, I want to build a decision tree to predict the data for test data

I have test and train data in excel sheet.

vc2.csv file has below dataset

==========================================
Sunny,Hot,High,Weak
Sunny,Hot,High,Strong
Overcast,Hot,High,Weak
Rain,Mild,High,Weak
Rain,Cool,Normal,Weak
Rain,Cool,Normal,Strong
Overcast,Cool,Normal,Strong
Sunny,Mild,High,Weak
Sunny,Cool,Normal,Weak
Rain,Mild,Normal,Weak
Sunny,Mild,Normal,Strong
Overcast,Mild,High,Strong
Overcast,Hot,Normal,Weak

## Rain,Mild,High,Strong

### and vc2_labels.txt has following content ( here 0 means No and 1 means Yes )

0
0
1
1
1
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
1

### 0

and vc2_test.csv file has
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Overcast,Hot,High,Weak
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Based on vc2_test.csv input data, i want to predict play the game in the given weather conditions is possible or not.

Please help me with sample code to solve this problem in Tensorflow C++.

Comment: answer for this is appreciated. ...